# Move issues from Bitbucket to Github

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I just moved to Github and I want to move all of my closed issues and open issues from Bitbucket over to Github.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This script should do the job: https://github.com/vbabiy/bitbucket_issue_migration

However, it's advisable to go through the code in the script and verify that it's exactly what you need or run the script on a test repo before actually doing the migration.

Answer (score 5):

Good luck with getting [that python script](https://github.com/vbabiy/bitbucket_issue_migration), [which @thameera referred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21845132/463785), working! I wasn't able to do that and I wrote a simple console application which does the job: https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/bitbucket-issues-to-github It also works for private bitbucket repositories. However, it has no documents and instructions for now.

Comment: I just tested it and the script @thameera referred is working very well (quite a pleasant surprise)! I guess they have fixed a bunch of things since you posted your answer.